# mvn command not found only in intellij terminal

Tags: linux, maven, intellij-idea

Just installed pop_os, switched over from MacOS, and I'm having a problem where I can run certain commands in the pop_os terminal window but not within the intellij terminal window.

Trying to run a simple "mvn clean install" in the Intellij terminal window, but i'm told mvn command not found.

In pop_os terminal when I run "which mvn" i'm told that the binary is in "/usr/bin/mvn". When I navigate to that directory in the same terminal window I can see mvn binary is present.. But I navigate to the same directory in intellij terminal window sure enough I cannot see the mvn binary anywhere (surprised_pikachu.png).

Please help?

Comment: Did you install IntelliJ IDEA via snap or via tar.gz?

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , or [unix.se] or possibly [apple.se] , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions. AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I installed via pop shop in pop os

Comment: Does it help if you install and run IntelliJ IDEA from the tar.gz official distribution available at https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html? pop shop can limit process access to the system binaries and run it in a sandbox.

Comment: @CrazyCoder i installed via tar.gz and didn't have the issue. think you're right, pop shop was the root cause. thanks for your help!